# Debouncing / throttling a callback in React using hooks without waiting for the user to stop typing to get the update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, throttling, debouncing

I'm using React `16.8.6` with Hooks and Formik `1.5.7` to build a form with a preview of the content that will be generated with that data later on. The form runs fine on its own, but as long as I render the preview as well, everything becomes a bit slow and sluggish.

I've fixed that debouncing the `onChange` of the form using `setTimeout`, but I'd like it to be called periodically even if the user keeps typing:

```js
const Preview = ({ values: { name = '', message = '' } }) => (<div className="preview">
  <p><strong>{ name }</strong></p>
  { message.split(/\r?\n\r?\n/g).filter(Boolean).map((text, i) => (<p key={ i }>{ text }</p>)) }
</div>);

const Form = ({ onChange }) => {
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({});
  
  // Let's assume this is internal code from Formik...:
  
  const handleChange = React.useCallback(({ target }) => {
    setValues(values => {
      const nextValues = ({ ...values, [target.name]: target.value });
      
      onChange(nextValues);
    
      return nextValues;
    });
  }, []);
  
  return (<form>
    <input type="text" value={ values.name || '' } name="name" onChange={ handleChange } />
    <textarea value={ values.message || '' } name="message" onChange={ handleChange } />
  </form>);
};

const App = () => {
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = React.useState({});
  const timeoutRef = React.useRef();
  
  React.useEffect(() => window.clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current), []);
  
  const handleFormChange = React.useCallback((values) => {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current);
    
    timeoutRef.current = window.setTimeout(() => setFormValues(values), 500);
  }, []);
  
  return (<div className="editor">
    <Form onChange={ handleFormChange } />
    <Preview values={ formValues } />
  </div>);
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

body,
input,
textarea {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.editor {
  display: flex;
}

form,
.preview {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 480px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 8px;
  
}

input,
textarea {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 0 auto 8px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.preview {
  border-left: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a custom `withThrottledCallback` hook that takes care of that and replaces/combines these lines:

```
const timeoutRef = React.useRef();

React.useEffect(() => window.clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current), []);

const handleFormChange = React.useCallback((values) => {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current);

    timeoutRef.current = window.setTimeout(() => setFormValues(values), 500);
}, []);
```

Into something like this:

```
const throttledHandleFormChange = useThrottledCallback((values) => {
    setFormValues(values);
}, 500, []);
```

And that fires regularly every 500 ms even if the user keeps typing.

This way, rather than using `setTimeout` directly, you would be able to reuse this functionality declaratively, just like Dan Abramov suggests for `setInterval` in [Making setInterval Declarative with React Hooks](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/).

It will look something like this:

```js
function useThrottledCallback(callback, delay, deps) {
  const timeoutRef = React.useRef();
  const callbackRef = React.useRef(callback);
  const lastCalledRef = React.useRef(0);

  // Remember the latest callback:
  //
  // Without this, if you change the callback, when setTimeout kicks in, it
  // will still call your old callback.
  //
  // If you add `callback` to useCallback's deps, it will also update, but it
  // might be called twice if the timeout had already been set.

  React.useEffect(() => {
    callbackRef.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Clear timeout if the components is unmounted or the delay changes:
  React.useEffect(() => window.clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current), [delay]);

  return React.useCallback((...args) => {
    // Clear previous timer:
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current);

    function invoke() {
      callbackRef.current(...args);
      lastCalledRef.current = Date.now();
    }

    // Calculate elapsed time:
    const elapsed = Date.now() - lastCalledRef.current;

    if (elapsed >= delay) {
      // If already waited enough, call callback:
      invoke();
    } else {
      // Otherwise, we need to wait a bit more:
      timeoutRef.current = window.setTimeout(invoke, delay - elapsed);
    }
  }, deps);
}

const Preview = ({ values: { name = '', message = '' } }) => (<div className="preview">
  <p><strong>{ name }</strong></p>
  { message.split(/\r?\n\r?\n/g).filter(Boolean).map((text, i) => (<p key={ i }>{ text }</p>)) }
</div>);

const Form = ({ onChange }) => {
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({});
  
  // Let's assume this is internal code from Formik...:
  
  const handleChange = React.useCallback(({ target }) => {
    setValues(values => {
      const nextValues = ({ ...values, [target.name]: target.value });
      
      onChange(nextValues);
    
      return nextValues;
    });
  }, []);
  
  return (<form>
    <input type="text" value={ values.name || '' } name="name" onChange={ handleChange } />
    <textarea value={ values.message || '' } name="message" onChange={ handleChange } />
  </form>);
};

const App = () => {
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = React.useState({});
    
  const throttledHandleFormChange = useThrottledCallback((values) => {
    setFormValues(values);
  }, 500, []);
  
  return (<div className="editor">
    <Form onChange={ throttledHandleFormChange } />
    <Preview values={ formValues } />
  </div>);
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

body,
input,
textarea {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.editor {
  display: flex;
}

form,
.preview {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 480px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 8px;
  
}

input,
textarea {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 0 auto 8px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

.preview {
  border-left: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

You can also find declarative version of `setTimeout` and `setInterval`, `useTimeout` and `useInterval`, plus a custom `useThrottledCallback` hook written in TypeScript in https://www.npmjs.com/package/@swyg/corre.